# Background image that change smoothly with a timer

Tags: flutter

I would like to implement and array with the path of different assets as a background.
The timer is working properly but the problem is there is no smooth transition.
I don't know why only works sometimes. I know that FadeInImage is used normally to await network images, perhaps that's the issue.
Is there any other way to achieve this goal?

```
 @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (timer) {
    setState(() {
      posbefore = pos;
      pos = random.nextInt(backgroundImages.length);
    });
  });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Scaffold(
    body:
    Stack(
      children: [ 
      Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: FadeInImage(placeholder: AssetImage('assets/'+backgroundImages[posbefore]), 
          image: AssetImage('assets/'+backgroundImages[pos]),
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
      ),
      Container()...
```

I found below approaches:
First use the CarouselSlider plugin

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Scaffold(
    body:
    Stack(
      children: [
      CarouselSlider(  
        options: CarouselOptions(autoPlay: true,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 5),
          autoPlayCurve: Curves.linear,
          viewportFraction: 1,
        ),
        items: backgroundImages.map((item) =>
          Container(
            child: Image.asset('assets/'+item, fit: BoxFit.fill, width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,),
          )
        ).toList(),
      ),
      Container()...
```

Second

```
      AnimatedSwitcher( 
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
        transitionBuilder: (Widget image, Animation<double> animation) {
        return FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: image,);
        },
        child: Image.asset('assets/'+backgroundImages[pos], key: ValueKey(pos), fit: BoxFit.fill,),
      ),
      Container(
```

The problem of my question lies in the use of a keyValue. I need to map the transition with the index change.